# winget install -e --id Microsoft.WindowsSDKに失敗する。

Tags: windows

表題の通りです。
以下のコマンドを実行した結果
winget install Microsoft.WindowsSDK
終了コードでインストーラーが失敗しました: 2008

と帰ってきます。
これはどのように解決すれば良いでしょうか。(公式を見てもこのエラーコードが見つからず)

Comment: Windows のバージョンを確認・質問に追記してみてください。 / インストーラをダウンロードする方法も用意されているようです。 https://developer.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

winget側に [Installer failed with exit code: 2008](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/issues/1818) で報告されていて、まだ未解決なようです。最新状況はこのIssueの動向を追うことになりそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほどですね・・・